# Queue items missing

Tags: c#, class, queue

I have a class with 2 queues - a and b.
When I insert values to the second queue(queue b) all values from the first one(queue a) are being removed.
Here is part of the class:

```
class SuperMarket
{
    private Queue<string> a;
    private Queue<string> b;

    public SuperMarket()
    {
        this.a = new Queue<string>();
        this.b = new Queue<string>();
    }

    public void InsertToA(string name)
    {
        this.a.Insert(name);
    }
    public void InsertToB(string name)
    {
        this.b.Insert(name);
    }
```

this is the main program:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SuperMarket a = new SuperMarket();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Names For first");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        while (name.CompareTo("aaa") != 0)
        {
            a.InsertToA(name);
            name = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Names For second");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        while (name.CompareTo("aaa") != 0)
        {
            a.InsertToB(name);
            name = Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

What might cause this effect?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: yes I did... 
When I insert to queue b - it shows me that there is nothing in a... 
:(

Comment: May I suggest using .Enqueue(name) instead of Insert? What kind of queue are you using? .Net Generics?

Comment: BTW... post the rest of the code so we can have a better idea

Comment: I can use onlye the "regular" function... (insert, remove...)

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: I only asked because Queue<T> does not have an "Insert"

Comment: I use the generic one...
Strange, until now I just use the Insert function and it worked

Comment: See also: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few years later, I can easily answer my own question:

```
    public void InsertToA(string name)
    {
        this.a.Enqueue(name);
    }
    public void InsertToB(string name)
    {
        this.b.Enqueue(name);
    }
```

--> One should use Enqueue instead of Insert when working with generics in c#.